# R -- frequencies within a variable for repeating values

Tags: r, count, duplicates

I've got a column A, which has several values, some of them repeating. So, example: A = c(5, 9, 6, 5, 5). I need to go through A and count the frequencies of each of the values in A. So, for this example, for the set of 5s in A, there are 3 occurancies of 5s. I need to save these frequencies so I can use them in another calculation. By the way, I have several other variables in this dataset.

How do I do this?
Thanks.

Comment: You can try `table(A)`

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error when trying that:Error in table(datasetname) : 
  attempt to make a table with >= 2^31 elements

Comment: Looks like your data is really big.  How big is it?  Perhaps, using `data.table` might be an option.  `library(data.table); setDT(yourdf)[, .N, A]`

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting this error, which does not allow me to use data.table functions: > library(data.table)
Error in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called ‘chron’
In addition: Warning message:
package ‘data.table’ was built under R version 3.2.1 
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘data.table’

Comment: You may need to upgrade R and `data.table`

Comment: Also, I just dropped several columns, so my data set is smaller, but I am still getting the error I got when using table(datasetname)

Comment: Can you show the `dim(dataset)`

Comment: Thanks akrun, but I already have the latest version of R. I upgraded last week.

Comment: Here it is, akrun: [1] 47999   200

Comment: I don't know if that cause bottleneck for `table`, but this seems to be comparatively easy with `data.table`

Comment: Thanks akrun. The data.table worked for me. I had to upgrade my R Studio, which I had not done when I upgraded R. Do you know how I can reference the counts that are produced by the setDT command?

Comment: What do you mean by reference the counts?

Comment: I need to use these counts in a calculation for a series of variables, and then I need to use the results of those calculations to make a plot.

Comment: You can do all the calculations inside the data.table.  For e.g. `setDT(yourdf)[, .N, by = A] [, Newcol:= N+anothercol]`

Comment: No problem.  If you come across any doubts, you can always post at SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
library(data.table)#v1.9.4+
setDT(yourdf)[, .N, by = A]
```